# How to install XAMPP?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, 32-bit, lamp

Hi all im a noob on Ubuntu/Linux World,

So i need some that give a full tutorial to How to install [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) from apachefriends.org correctly on Ubuntu 11.10 + all beyond Ubuntu for 32 bit and also 64 bit Desktop Version.. and also i need this:

- Make a Folder on Your Home Folder and Linked to **htdocs** from *Apache Web Server*
- Make a GUI interface for Xmapp
- Start Xampp when Ubuntu Boot Up or Start Ubuntu

(Note: i ask it for both X86 and X64 so people in the further can see the tutorials)

---

#### New Data:

What i did was i download from [apachefriends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for now and i also what to say that I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.10 X64 bit for Dell Studio 1558 processor intel i3

i will let you know guys which solution was the best, and it is for a Desktop Version of Ubuntu 11.10 (Laptop 15 inch screen ^_^ ) not Server Ubuntu

Comment: if you need any technical specs of my Computer pleas let me know i will add it to the Question

Comment: Try following these instructions written for ubuntu 11.10 . It also tell you to start the lampp during boot and how to secure your server .
This tutorial should also work for ubuntu 10.04 and above http://menatronics.blogspot.in/2012/01/lampp-installation-to-securing-your.html

Comment: Hello? Any update?

Answer (score 9):

Why not just do `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ libapache2-mod-perl2` ? The `lamp-server^` package should install Apache2, MySQL, PHP, (which should already be set up to work together). The `libapache2-mod-perl2` should add Perl support to Apache.*

For permissions, I usually do this:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

Then you can make a link in your home folder that points to the webserver directory:

```
sudo ln -s /var/www /home/<yourusername>/www
```

By default, when you install Apache this way, it is started on boot.

I think it would be much easier to use the Ubuntu's way to install software on Ubuntu. That way, you will automatically get updates to your software through the package manager.

*I haven't done this before. You may need to follow the end of [this page](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-apache2-webserver-with-phpcgi-and-perl-support-in-ubuntu-server.html) from the heading "Configure a cgi-bin directory" on.

Comment: i didn't test bro because that the only way i know to used and right now i have data in MySql so it should work, so for now unistalling or lose data i should go where i know

Answer (score 1):

several months ago i've solved that problem when i change my 32bit to 64 bit.
note: xampp for linux  called lampp. because lampp was compiled for 32bit so when you want to using in 64bit ubuntu, 32bit shared libraries must be installed.
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` (64bit ubuntu only)

1. Download lampp in http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html
2. for each user has a web folder (example /home/astro/public_html), uncomment this configuration on lampp apache configuration

   `sudo vim /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

from
 `#Include etc/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`
to 
`Include etc/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

you can change default folder name in /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

1. Actually lampp was included GUI for start or stop daemon (like xampp in windows)
   `sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py` (must using a root privileges using sudo, but you can do some trick like changing sudoers,etc).
2. and for "Start Xampp when Ubuntu Boot Up or Start Ubuntu". 
   `sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp /etc/init.d/lampp`
   `sudo update-rc.d lampp defaults`

hopefully works and sorry for my english :)

Comment: after i run sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py i got this error (xampp-control-panel.py:11290): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Comment: Heads up: The `ia32-libs` packages was finally dropped from the latest Ubuntu releases.